# soap: Content is not allowed in prolog; @-sign; sugar-crm

Tags: java, soap, sugarcrm

i have a problem with my soap connection to a sugar crm: Everything works fine, until I want to transmit a @-sign, then I get this exception.

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

What can I do to fix my problem?

Thanks flo

Comment: Which version of Axis are you using?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but thats the output from the manifest:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 1.4.2_08-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Comment: There is no information in the question to go on. What does it mean to "transmit a @-sign"? How about some code that does that?

Comment: Transmit a @-sign means to transfer a string with an included @-sign. for example: when I call soap.send("abcdefg") everything works fine, but when I call soap.send("abcdefg@abcdefg") i'll get a "content is not allowed in prolog" exception. when i write soap.send("<![CDATA[abcdefg@abcdefg]]>") everything is fine again.

I don't know exactly what peace of code I should show you, because the soap connection was auto-generated from WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :) There was a problem in a query processing the @-sign.